# Are there any ways to detect that user click on the link I shared on Facebook, Messenger?

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph, user-agent, messenger

- As I mention on title, I'm finding a solution to detect whenever user click on my website from Facebook.
- I 've try to do that by reading userAgent from the request, that user agent may be a string look like this when the my site is opened on Facebook 's internal webview:

```sh
*Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Redmi Note 8 Build/PKQ1.190616.001; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/85.0.4183.81 Mobile Safari/537.36 [**FB_IAB**/Orca-Android;**FBAV**/280.0.0.16.110;]*
```

and then with keyword **FB_IAB** I can find out that the user clicked from Facebook.

- But there still a problem that on some device, when user click the link on Facebook, it doesn't open the internal webview but open external browser. So that I got the user-agent like this:

```sh
*Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.141 Safari/534.24 XiaoMi/MiuiBrowser/12.5.2-go*
```

- (behavior on Xiaomi). Thus, I can not detect user agent is from Facebook or not.
- Could you please suggest me the way to solve this problem ? Thank you!

Comment: Check if the `fbclid` parameter that Facebook appends to all outgoing links on desktop, is also set in this situation maybe?

Comment: Oh, thank you. But on Messenger, it will not if user click the link from preview image. Sorry because my question is not generic, what I mean is both Facebook and Messenger. Anyway, thanks for supporting me, @CBroe

Comment: If there aren’t _any_ additional parameters added by Facebook, then you probably just can’t detect this specific situation.

Comment: Oh, I had tested. On messenger of android there are two case: 
1. Click link from url text -> open internal web view (no additional params, userAgent contain FBAV): -> detect that it is from facebook platform
2. Click link from preview image -? open default browser of device ( no additional params, user agent of browser) -> can not detect